# C++ Compound Logical Operators not Working with Comparison Operator

Tags: c++, logical-operators, comparison-operators

I have two cases in a program I am writing where i am using compound logical operators to compare a variable against multiple values efficiently. One of the is working just fine. I have an array of characters, and I want to check if one of the elements is equal to one of two values without having to restate the variable. I also have an integer called hourInt, but this is not important. The code I used for the conditional is as follows:

```
 if (charArray[8] == 'P' || 'p' && hourInt != 12){
    hourInt += 12;
 }
 if (charArray[8] == 'A' || 'a' && hourInt == 12){
    hourInt -= 12;
 }
```

And both of these conditionals perform their job correctly - they check whether charArray[8] is equal to one of the two values. But then, later on in the program, I tried using compound logical operators again. I have a two-character string called meridies, and I want to see whether it is not equal to one of four values. I set up a conditional with compound logical operators as follows:

```
if (meridies != "AM" || "am" || "PM" || "pm"){
    cout << "Error: Unknown value for the meridies." << endl;
    return inputTime();
}
```

Unlike the first conditional, which correctly compared the values, this second one always returns true, even if meridies is indeed equal to one of the four cases. I know I could just set this up as four different comparisons each with their own logical operator, but I am just wondering why this second conditional doesn't work whereas the first one does.

Comment: None of them work.

Comment: Where did you learn the concept of "compound logical operators"? They simply don't exist in C++. `&&` and `||` take two **boolean** arguments and return a boolean argument. They aren't a replacement for the English words "and" and "or".

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I thought that code worked so I called it 'Compound Logical Operators', as if it worked it must exist, but as you'll see in my comment to the accepted answer, the conditional didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you might need to read up on how operators work (and operator precedence).

Firstly, this is a nonsense:

```cpp
charArray[8] == 'P' || 'p'
```

You are saying, if (charArray[8] == 'P') is true, or 'p' is true. 'p' will always be true, because it is not zero. It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do with that code, but I assume something along these lines?

```cpp
if ( (charArray[8] == 'P' || charArray[8] == 'p') && hourInt != 12)
```

As for this:

```cpp
if (meridies != "AM" || "am" || "PM" || "pm")
```

**IF** meridas is a std::string, then it should be:

```cpp
if (meridies != "AM" && meridies != "am" && meridies != "PM" && meridies != "pm")
```

If however meridies is a char array, then you should be doing:

```cpp
if (strcmp(meridies, "AM") != 0 && 
    strcmp(meridies, "am") != 0 && 
    strcmp(meridies, "PM") != 0 && 
    strcmp(meridies, "pm") != 0)
```

Comment: Yeah I see that now, thank you. I thought that the first conditional looked weird when I typed it in as I learned a while ago that stuff like that should not work, but it seemed to do its job so I left it. Turns out that another part of the code was just doing the work of the conditional for it (it was a spaghetti-code program I wrote at 2am). Thanks for the answer - I'll accept it when it lets me.